# Is hadoop's job ThreadSafe?

Tags: hadoop

Anyone knows if `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job` is thread-safe? In my application I create a thread for each job, and then `waitForCompletion`. And I have another monitor thread that checks every job's state with `isComplete`.

Is that safe? Are jobs thread-safe? Documentation doesn't seem to mention anything about it...

Thanks
Udi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the others, I also use threads to submit jobs in parallel and wait for their completion. You just have to use a job class instance per thread. If you share same job instances over multiple threads, you have to take care of the synchronization by yourself.

Comment: Are you using scheduler wich runs jobs in parralel?

Comment: @David Grunzman yes it is a mixture of quartz and chains of dependend jobs, some of them may run in parallel so I submit them parallel.

Comment: Hi @ThomasJungblut , can you give some example code about using many threads for hadoop jobs ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to write a separate thread for each job? What exactly is your use case?

You can run multiple jobs in your Hadoop cluster. Do you have dependencies between the multiple jobs?

Suppose you have 10 jobs running. 1 job fails then would you need to re-run the 9 successful tasks.

Finally, job tracker will take care of scheduling multiple jobs on the Hadoop cluster. If you do not have dependencies then you should not be worried about thread safety. If you have dependencies then you may need to re-think your design.

Comment: Im using Job.waitForCompletion(). This method is IO blocks until completion is done. If Ill run everything in a single thread, the thread will run serial and not parallel...

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are.. Actually the files is split in blocks and each block is executed on a separate node. all the map tasks run in parallel and then are fed to the the reducer after they are done. There is no question of synchronization as you would think about in multi threaded program. In multi threaded program all the threads are running on the same box and since they share some of the data you have to synchronize them

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you need another kind of parallelism on the map task level, you should override run() method in your mapper and work with multiple threads there. Default implementation calls setup(), then map() times number of records to process, and finally it calls cleanup() method once.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

If you are checking whether the jobs have finished I think you are a bit confused about how Map reduce works. You ought to be letting Hadoop do that for itself.

Comment: I don't agree. In my case, I have component that runs multiple jobs in a flow, one after another, and for some jobs I want to stop process (end-2-end) running if that particular job fails.

Another case is having REST service that reads status information of  few jobs from HBase table, and has to call custom Hadoop code to check if job with particular job_id has finnished - otherwise no status information is persisted in the HBase table yet.